# file_put_contents inside a while

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Is it possible to put the `file_put_contents()` function inside a `while()` loop?

I am trying to get my script to write lines into a text file - there's over 4 thousand lines to write.

```
$glassquery = $db->query("SELECT item FROM glass");

while($glass = $glassquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    file_put_contents('download.txt', $glass['item'] . PHP_EOL);
}
```

So it's writing the item name into the text file then the next one on a new line.

Comment: Did you try it? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
while($glass = $glassquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    file_put_contents('download.txt', $glass['item'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

This will write the lines one at a time without erasing previous lines.